# How to edit a file owned by root on SSH connect

Tags: linux, ssh, file-permissions

Hi I'm sure there is some way of doing what I want, but maybe I'm just attacking it the wrong way. Hope someone can help.

I have a dev box that I SSH in to from several other machines. In order to debug remotely I need to configure my debugger with my client machine's IP, which changes when I log in from different machines. I'm getting bored of doing this manually all the time so thought I'd try and automate it.

I'm creating a script that is automatically run upon SSH connection that will modify a configuration setting in a PHP ini file. The problem is the PHP ini files are all owned by root so I'm not sure how to modify those files if I'm just logging in as a normal user.

There's not really a security concern with my dev box so I could just change the owner of the ini file, but I wanted it to be more automated than that.

My current attempt is a python script located in my home dir, which is called from .bashrc when I connect via SSH. I don't see how I can gain root privileges from there, I am pretty new to linux though. I thought maybe there would be some other method I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file that is owned by root. You clearly need to either find a way to mark the file as modifiable by you; or a way for you to elevate your privileges so that you are allowed to modify it.

This leads to the two traditional unix approachs to doing this. They are:

1. To create a group with which to mark the file, ie. initdebug; chgrp/chmod the file so it has the initdebug group and is group writable; and, add yourself to the initdebug group so you can use the group write permission to modify the file.
2. To create a very small, audited binary executable (this won't work with a script) that will perform the specific modifications you desire (for simplicity I would suggest copying one of a selection of root owned PHP ini files into the right place). Then chown'ing the file so it is owned by root, and setting the suid bit on the executable so it will execute as root.

You can also combine the two approaches, either:

1. Not making yourself a member of the initdebug group or suid on the executable, but rather setting group of the executable to initdebug and setting its sgid bit; or,
2. Keeping the executable suid root but making it only executable by initdebug and therefore only executable by users added to that group.

The security trade off is in the ease/risk of privilege escalation should someone hack your account. If there is a stack/heap overflow or similar vulnerability in the executable and it is executing as root, then you are gone. If the PHP ini file can be modified to open a remote-vulnerability then if they can directly access the ini file you are gone.

As I suspect the latter is possible, you are probably best off with a small executable.

Note: As I alluded to above, unix does not acknowledge the s[ug]id bits on scripts (defined as anything using the #!... interpreter syntax). Hence, you will have to use something you can compile down to a binary. So that probably means either C, C++, Java(using gcj), ML, Scheme(mit), Haskell(ghc).

If you haven't done any C or C++ programming before, I would recommend one of the others as a suid binary is not a project with which to learn C/C++. If you don't know any of the other languages, I would recommend either ML or Java as the easiest to to write something small and simple.

(btw, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers includes a list of alternative compilers you can use. Just make sure it compiles to native, not bytecode. As far as the OS is concerned a bytecode vm is just another interpreter).

Comment: Hi, that sounds like the best answer to my question after reading some similar ideas in other threads. I think I would probably create some C script like you mentioned. First though, as I'm strapped for time, I going to just change the file permissions and see if I can just get it working that way for now. Interested in doing some C again though :)

Comment: Here's a link to something similar suggested that I read: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369

Comment: Just like to say I went with your suggestion and created a small C program that does exactly what I need. No password prompts or need to modify permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with insert your user to sudoers file on mechine that you want to remote,
for the example you can see my blog.
this is the url : http://nanamo3lyana.blogspot.com/2012/06/give-priviledge-normal-user-as-root.html

and then on your automaticly script add sudo on your command.

i'm sorry my english not good.

Comment: That's a good idea, I don't think it will work for me unfortunately as I don't want to allow sudo access without a password.